# In javafx my mediaplayer freezes if I close and re-open the scene

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

Me and my friend are writing a small javafx 8 program used to rickroll people. Once you open it, if you try to close it it comes back again, and dragging it away doesnt work either. We're getting one problem though: once you start the program and then shut it down, after 1 second it re=opens fine, but the mediaplayer freezes, and we can't figure out why. Edit: The mediaplayer doesn't freeze Instantly when you re-open, 1 second after it re-opens it freezes. So it re-opens, plays just fine, but if you wait, and let it play for 1 second after the re-open, it freezes.

this is where how the mediaplayer is created:

```
    Media media = new Media(getClass().getResource("/res/video.mp4").toString());
    mediaPlayer = new javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer(media);
    mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);
    mediaPlayer.setCycleCount(MediaPlayer.INDEFINITE);
    MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);
```

When the window is closed, we pause the video for 1 second, using this code:

```
  primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(WindowEvent we) {
        primaryStage.close();
        mediaPlayer.pause();
            System.out.println("pause");
        timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(
            Duration.millis(1000),
            e -> {
                openWindow(primaryStage);
            }
        ));
        timeline.setCycleCount(1);
        timeline.play();
        }
    });
```

and finally the `openWindow` method is what opens t everything back up after the 1 second:

```
    private void openWindow(Stage primaryStage){
    primaryStage.show();
    mediaPlayer.play();
}
```

There is quite some stuff I left out, because I felt it was unnessicary. If you think you need more, I am willing to put my full code in here, but that is 101 lines long, which seemed a bit over the top.
I want to thank you for your help in advance, and I'm sorry if the question is unclear: I'm not really experienced...
kind regards
Luit Meinen

Edit: here is my full code:

```
    package rickroll;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
    import javafx.animation.Timeline;
    import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.Status;
import static javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.Status.PLAYING;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.WindowEvent;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Rickroll extends Application {
    private ArrayList<Stage> stages = new ArrayList<>();
    private Group root = new Group();
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private Timeline focusTimer, timeline;
    private Scene scene;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Media media = new Media(getClass().getResource("/res/video.mp4").toString());
        mediaPlayer = new javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer(media);
//        mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(false);
        mediaPlayer.setCycleCount(MediaPlayer.INDEFINITE);
        MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);
        stages.add(primaryStage);
        primaryStage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        Button button = new Button();
        button.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, e -> Platform.exit());

        for(int i = 1; Screen.getScreens().size() >= i; i++){

        }

        root.getChildren().add(mediaView);  
        root.getChildren().add(button);
        scene = new Scene(
            root, 
            Screen.getPrimary().getBounds().getWidth(), 
            Screen.getPrimary().getBounds().getWidth()
        );
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        Platform.setImplicitExit(false);

        focusTimer = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(
            Duration.millis(500),
            e -> {
                primaryStage.requestFocus();
                primaryStage.centerOnScreen();
                primaryStage.setMaximized(true);
            }
        ));
        focusTimer.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        focusTimer.play();

        primaryStage.setTitle("You just got Rick Rolled!");
        openWindow(primaryStage);

        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(WindowEvent we) {
            primaryStage.hide();
            mediaPlayer.pause();
                System.out.println("pause");
            timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(
                Duration.millis(1000),
                e -> {
                    openWindow(primaryStage);
                }
            ));
            timeline.setCycleCount(1);
            timeline.play();
            focusTimer.pause();
            }
        }); 

    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private void openWindow(Stage primaryStage){
        primaryStage.show();
        mediaPlayer.play();
        System.out.println("play");
        focusTimer.play();
    }

}
```

As you will see, there is some stuff in there that the question isnt about. like a start for doing this on multiple screens, and a temporary button to close the window. please ignore that part.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that its pausing while you are between opening/closing then its because you have `mediaPlayer.pause()` in your `onCloseRequest` handler. If however the problem is that it does not restart on opening up again I was unable to replicate it. Also what is the for loop's purpose?

Comment: Since it was too long for  comment, I edited my question. It now conatins full code. I apriciate that you're trying to help a lot!!! thanks

Comment: @Luit Updated Answer

Comment: The for loop's purpose is not yet existant. It will later become the loop that makes this program show on all your screens if you have multiple, but it does not yet do anything. just ignore it.  It pausing between opening and closing is supposed to happen. What I mean is that sometimes when I closed the screen, and then it comes back, it plays for a bit and suddenly stops (after about 1 second)... so it doesnt stop immediately, it takes a while

Answer (score 0):

Check the code below(it contains comments):

```
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.PauseTransition;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Rickroll extends Application {

    private ArrayList<Stage>    stages  = new ArrayList<>();

    private Group               root    = new Group();
    private Scene               scene;

    private MediaPlayer         mediaPlayer;
    private Timeline            focusTimer;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Initialise the MediaPlayer
        Media media = null;
        try {
            //change here with your video path
            media = new Media(getClass().getResource("/videos/video.mp4").toURI().toString());
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
            mediaPlayer.setCycleCount(MediaPlayer.INDEFINITE);
            // mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(false)
        } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        // Create the Media View
        MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);

        // Assuming that you want the Media to have the same size as the window
        //primaryStage.widthProperty()
        //      .addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> mediaView.setFitWidth(primaryStage.getWidth()))

        //primaryStage.heightProperty()
        //      .addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> mediaView.setFitHeight(primaryStage.getHeight()))

        // ?
        stages.add(primaryStage);

        // PrimaryStage
        primaryStage.setTitle("You just got Rick Rolled!");
        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(windowEvent -> {

            // Hide the stage
            primaryStage.hide();

            // Pause the Media Player
            mediaPlayer.pause();
            System.out.println("pause");

            // Use a pause transition to wait 1 second - 1000 milliseconds
            PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition();
            pause.setDuration(Duration.millis(1000));
            pause.play();
            pause.setOnFinished(finish -> openWindow(primaryStage));

            // Pause the focusTimer
            focusTimer.pause();
        });

        // Button
        Button button = new Button();
        button.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, e -> Platform.exit());

        // ? you want to know the primary screen size?
        for (int i = 1; Screen.getScreens().size() >= i; i++) {

        }

        // Add the children to the root
        root.getChildren().addAll(mediaView, button);
        // Scene
        scene = new Scene(root, Screen.getPrimary().getBounds().getWidth(), Screen.getPrimary().getBounds().getWidth());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        Platform.setImplicitExit(false);

        // Focus Timer
        focusTimer = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(500), e -> {
            primaryStage.requestFocus();
            primaryStage.centerOnScreen();
            primaryStage.setMaximized(true);
        }));
        focusTimer.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        focusTimer.play();

        // Open the primary stage
        openWindow(primaryStage);

    }

    /**
     * @param args
     *            the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    /**
     * Open the window and start the player
     * 
     * @param primaryStage
     */
    private void openWindow(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Show the primary stage
        primaryStage.show();

        // start the media player
        mediaPlayer.play();
        System.out.println("play");

        // start the focusTimer
        focusTimer.play();
    }

}
```

Comment: This code is so that when the X is pressed, and then the program shows again, it will continue where it left off. I don't want the song to continue when the screen isn't visible. I don't exactly get what you mean with the last sentence.

Comment: But I dont want the user to have the ability to exit the platform fully. When the X is pressed, I want it to wait 1 second, and then just resume where it left off in the music video

Comment: @Luit Completely rewritten your code.For any questions feel free to ask.It had several problems.I changed the `TimeLine` with a `PauseTransition`.

Comment: Hi,
Sadly changing the timer did not work. I've copied you code, but after closing the program, when it restarts it still pauses after a while.

Comment: @Luit After how much time is pausing?The correct word is resuming and not restarting.

Comment: It pauses after 1 second

Comment: @Luit Maybe the video you have has some encoding problems.It happens,and `JavaFX` decoder is a mysterious creature.I have run the program multiple times using different videos with duration from 12 seconds to 1 minute and i am not facing the problem of pausing even if i close and reopen the window multiple times.So i recommend that you try with a different video or even 2-3 different videos to see what happens.

Comment: I have now tried it with 4 random other videos, and got the exact smae problem every single time.

Comment: @Luit Hm very strange... You have copied exactly this code and this behaviour occur? What is your Java Version?

Comment: Yes, I copied your exact code and got this behaviour with multiple videos. I  am currently running java version 8.